# Multiple sed rewrites on a line fail to work

Tags: sed

I am writing a TeX file and am using `|...|` as a shorthand for `\verb|...|` and attemping to accomplish this with

```
sed 's/|\(.*.\)|/\\verb|\1|/g'
```

However, if I have two instance of `|...|` on the same line, then only the first is rewritten. For example,

```
printf " test |1| then |2| \n finally |3|" | sed 's/|\(.*.\)|/\\verb|\1|/g'
```

results in

```
 test \verb|1| then |2| 
 finally \verb|3|
```

Notice that the second usage of the `|...|` did not get translated properly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf " test |1| then |2| \n finally |3|" | sed 's/|\([^|]*[^|]\)|/\\verb|\1|/g'
```

Your RE doesn't work as expected is because sed captures *longest*  match. So, for first line of your example, expression `.*.` captures `1| then |2` as a single match. I changed expression to `[^|]*[^|]` in order to prohibit capturing vertical bars.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! Changing it to sed 's/|\(.*.\)|/\\verb+\1+/g' made it clearer what you said :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/|[^|]*|/\\verb&/g' file
```